# How can we create a dynamic sql query to run without considering if the parameters are passed or not in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

I am using VS 2012 and SQL Express

I am trying to build a windows forms application to search through a database in C# and   it has different controls on the form which are passed as parameters to the query.

The parameters in the query are not necessarily passed some times

I am trying with the following code sample.

```
SELECT a.ID AS 'DealID', a.TradeDate, c.COMPANYNAME AS 'Seller Company', 
       a.SellCommission, h.BROKER_FULLNAME AS 'Seller Trader', 
       j.DisplayName AS 'Seller Broker', d.COMPANYNAME AS 'Buyer Company', 
       a.BuyCommission, g.BROKER_FULLNAME AS 'Buyer Trader', 
       i.DisplayName AS 'Buyer Broker', e.PRODUCT_NAME, f.TYPE_DESC AS 'Quantity Type',
       f.NBR_OF_GALLONS AS 'Quantity Multiplier', a.ContractVolume, a.TotalVolume, 
       a.DeliveryPoint, a.Price, a.ContractStart, a.ContractEnd
FROM Confirmations AS a WITH (nolock) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY AS c WITH (nolock) 
  ON c.COMPANY_ID = a.SellCompany
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY AS d WITH (nolock) 
  ON d.COMPANY_ID = a.BuyCompany 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BIOPRODUCTTYPES AS e WITH (nolock) 
  ON e.ID = a.ProductID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BIO_QUANTITY_TYPE AS f WITH (nolock) 
  ON f.ID = a.QuantityTypeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANYBROKER AS g WITH (nolock) 
  ON g.COMPANYBROKER_ID = a.BuyTrader 
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANYBROKER AS h WITH (nolock) 
  ON h.COMPANYBROKER_ID = a.SellTrader 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users AS i WITH (nolock) 
  ON i.ID = a.BuyBroker 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users AS j WITH (nolock) 
  ON j.ID = a.SellBroker
WHERE (@fromdate IS NULL OR @fromdate=' ' OR a.TradeDate >= @fromdate) 
       AND (@todate IS NULL OR @todate=' ' OR a.TradeDate <= @todate) 
       AND (@buycompanyname IS NULL 
            OR @buycompanyname="" 
            OR a.BuyCompany = (SELECT COMPANY_ID
                               FROM COMPANY
                               WHERE (COMPANYNAME = @buycompanyname)))              
       AND (@sellcompanyname IS NULL 
            OR @sellcompanyname="" 
            OR a.SellCompany = (SELECT COMPANY_ID
                                FROM COMPANY
                                WHERE (COMPANYNAME =@sellcompanyname))) 
       AND (@product IS NULL OR @product="" OR e.PRODUCT_NAME= @product)";
```

Rather than using the above query, can I dynamically create a query, based on the parameters I passed which seems more logical as it doesn't look for the records if the column in the table has a null value.

Comment: I think you're missing some parens as well, i.e. I would think you want _(@todate IS NULL OR (@todate=' ' OR a.TradeDate <= @todate))_ instead of what you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling a stored procedure, I'd suggest dynamically building the SQL string to only use the parameters you'll be using, then calling sp_executesql. The stored procedure would look like this:

```
DECLARE @sql =nvarchar(MAX), @Parameters nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Foo] WHERE Column1 = @Param1'
SET @Parameters = '@Param1 nvarchar(32), @Param2 nvarchar(32)'
IF(@Param2 is not null and @Param2 <> ' ') SET @sql = @sql + ' AND Column2 = @Param2'
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, @Parameters, @Param1, @Param2
```

The idea is basically the same if you're building the query string in C# instead of a stored procedure:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Foo] WHERE Column1 = @Param1";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", param1);
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
{
    command.CommandText += " AND Column2 = @Param2";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", param2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [ORM's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) where created for. By replacing your hard coded querys with somthing that builds your query at runtime (like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/)) and it builds the both the `SELECT` and the `WHERE` portions of the query for you.

With proper set up objects you could use Entity Framework like the following

```
Nullable<DateTime> fromDate = //...
Nullable<DateTime> toDate = //...
string buyCompany = //...

//(Snip)

using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var query = ctx.Order;

    if(fromDate.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(ent=> ent.TradeDate >= fromDate.Value);
    if(toDate.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(ent => ent.TradeDate <= toDate.Value);
    if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(buyCompany) == false)
        query = query.Where(ent => ent.BuyCompany.CompanyName = buyCompany);

    //(Snip)

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just build your sql query string out.

Set your `SqlCommand.CommandType` to `CommandType.Text`
then set your parameters with `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWidthValue(string, object);`