# Multi inputs search doesnt work properly

Tags: sql

Well my problem is that have a SQL sentence and do the job but not how I want it, AND I want search by action, type, city, or rooms and just show what people select on the queries and with my code it just search all the records,

SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `inmuebles` 
WHERE 
    action = 'sell' 
    OR type = 'apartment' 
    OR city = 'Los Angeles' 
    AND rooms BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

Any help with be appreciated

Comment: You can refer the following. It might answer your question



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977917/how-can-we-create-a-dynamic-sql-query-to-run-without-considering-if-the-paramete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change OR to AND, because now your conditions are too loose.

```
SELECT * FROM `inmuebles` 
WHERE action = 'sell' 
AND type = 'apartment' 
AND city = 'Los Angeles') 
AND rooms BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! its Works now, just need to fill all inputs Great! :D many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `inmuebles` 
WHERE 
(
  action = 'sell' 
  OR type = 'apartment' 
  OR city = 'Los Angeles' 
)
AND rooms BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```